# PHP define() and PDO connection string issues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made a small test script while trying to solve issues with sessions going missing after switching to PDO.

In testing the script I am finding that every other load of the page gets

`Access denied for user 'DB_USER'@'[ip snipped]' (using password: YES)`

So DB_USER is uninterpolated for every second load.  The first load of the page gets a successful connection.

Why is that?  PHP version is 5.4.42.

```
<?
session_start();
define("DB_HOST", "myserver");
define("DB_USER", "myuser");
define("DB_PASS", "mypass");
define("DB_NAME", "mydb");


class DB {  
    protected $link;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        return array('dsn', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        $this->connect();
    }
}

$db = new DB;
```

Comment: The real question is why are you serializing your `DB` object at all?

Comment: @Phil though I am not doing this in this script in my main script I store a User object which inherits from class DB.  As far as I know I do not serialize the DB object otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __wakeup() {
    $this->dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
    $this->connect();
}
```

will fix this.
But  the main problem is that you havent define variables like

```
protected $dsn;
```

So the wakup fails.